# Error en firebase syntax error

Tags: html, firebase, importación, error404, firebase-auth

```
`<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="es"> <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Documento</title>  </head> <body>
    <form action="">
        <div>
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" id="nombre">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
            <textarea id="mensaje"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
    </form>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <b>Nombre: </b> Mensaje
        </li>
        <li>
            <b>Nombre: </b> Mensaje
        </li>
    </ul> <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js"></script> <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script> <script> // Module declaration export function initializeFirebase() {  // Initialize Firebase and set up analytics   const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyB6igWT7Yjhyba6zMDRSjZWBYPRHcy5Pcs",
    authDomain: "mychat-a4b48.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "mychat-a4b48",
    storageBucket: "mychat-a4b48.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "34313160517",
    appId: "1:34313160517:web:c330809c3e1e696cf7e02c",
    measurementId: "G-7RY9LWQL95"   };

  const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);   const analytics = firebase.analytics();

  return app; }

// Initialize Firebase and set up analytics 
const app = initializeFirebase();

// Obtener el nombre del usuario 
const txtNombre = document.getElementById("nombre"); 
const nombre = txtNombre.value;

// Obtener el mensaje del usuario 
const txtMensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje"); 
const mensaje = txtMensaje.value;

// Enviar el mensaje analytics.logEvent("mensaje_enviado", {   nombre: nombre,
```

mensaje: mensaje });

```
</body> 
</html>`
```

[image: errores que salen en esta imagen]

*me sale todo esto
permissions-policy header: origin trial controlled feature not enables: interest -cohort
unexpected token export at firebase-app.js
cannot use import statement outside a module at firebase-analyti firebase-analytics.js unexpected token export at index
no se como solucionarlo ya que ya he intentado varias cosas, agradeceria su ayuda*